# Simple custom expression parser

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, javacc, parser-generator

I looked a little over the available parsers on the net but don't really understand what is the most suitable for my custom expression. 
(Antlr seems a little to heavyweight for my needs, but it's just a first impression)

I have the following expression that needs to be validated that it's well formed:

**IF(var1>var2;15;IF(var3<=var4;1;2))**

The expression translates to:
if the condition is true then the result is 15 else the other expression.

I need only to validate that this is well formed (no extra brackets, that there is always a first and second branch, that the IF keyword is used correctly, nested IFs etc..)

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: You can try using the SpEL parser of Spring (instead of an **if** you should use the ternary operator) http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html . It is as simple as **ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser(); Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("1+2*(2+7*(1+5))"); System.out.println(exp.getValue());** supports variables and other features.

Answer (score 1):

First, *write a grammar*.  Otherwise it will be unclear what is legal or not. (What you have written is not precise; for example, are you allowed to have a number after a relational?  a variable as the else part of of an IF?)  Grammar make this precise.

Second, if your grammar is only going to accept expressions, you can code it easily with a hand-written recursive descent grammar:  [see my SO answer on how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2336769/120163). Such a parser will do all the sanity checking you want.

If you are trying to parse a very complicated language, then JavaCC or ANTLR are better choices.